# MySQL - auto decrementing value

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let's say that I've got a table, like that (id is auto-increment):

```
id | col1 | col2
1  | 'msg'| 'msg'
2  | 'lol'| 'lol2'
3  | 'xxx'| 'x'
```

Now, I want to delete row number 2 and I get something like this

```
id | col1 | col2
1  | 'msg'| 'msg'
3  | 'xxx'| 'x'
```

The thing is, what I want to get is that:

```
id | col1 | col2
1  | 'msg'| 'msg'
2  | 'xxx'| 'x'
```

How can I do that in the EASIEST way (my knowledge about MySQL is very poor)?

Comment: From the database perspective, it shouldn't matter what value the id is as long as it's a unique value. Why do you need id values to be reset in this way?

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonable way of doing this. Remember that decrementing each value for a big db is going to be painful. Why does it matter anyways?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't do that.
Do not take an auto-incremented **unique identifier** as an ordinal number.
The word *"unique"* means that the identifier should be stuck to its row **forever**.

There is no connection between these numbers and enumerating.
Imagine you want to select records in alphabetical order. Where would your precious numbers go?
A database is not like an ordered list, as you probably think. It is not a flat file with rows stored in a predefined order. It has totally different ideology. Rows in the database do not have any order. And will be ordered only at select time, if it was explicitly set by `ORDER BY` clause.
Also, a database is supposed to do a search for you. So you can tell that with filtered rows or different ordering this auto-increment number will have absolutely nothing to do with the real rows positions.

If you want to enumerate the output - it's a presentation layer's job. Just add a counter on the PHP side.

And again: these numbers supposed to identify a certain record. If you change this number, you'd never find your record again.

Take this very site for example. Stack Overflow identifies its questions with such a number:

> stackoverflow.com/questions/**3132439**/mysql-auto-decrementing-value

So, imagine you saved this page address to a bookmark. Now Jeff comes along and renumbers the whole database. You press your bookmark and land on the different question. Whole site would become a terrible mess.

Remember: Renumbering unique identifiers is evil!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to this directly. Maybe you can do `"update"` operation. But you must do it for all record after your deleted record. It is very bad solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why using an auto-increment if you want to change it manually?

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to change the value of an auto_increment column. However, if you are sure you want to, the following should help.

If you are only deleting a single record at a time, you could use a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE table1 SET id = id - 1 WHERE id > 2;
COMMIT;
```

However if you delete multiple records, you will have to drop the column and re-add it. It is probably not guaranteed to put the rows in the same order as previously.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 DROP id;
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Also, if you have data that relies on these IDs, you will need to make sure it is updated.

Comment: Separate this "auto-decremented" column from your primary key column, and allow the primary to skip numbers. What's being suggested here (although a great answer to the question) is dangerous and bad database practice.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the only case when you may need to renumber an auto-increment field, is a case when you don't need an auto-increment at all.

Answer (score -1):

You can renumber the whole table like this:

```
SET @r := 0;
UPDATE  mytable
SET     id = (@r := @r + 1)
ORDER BY
        id;
```