# Deleting last row in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I delete the last row in a MySQL table and then insert a new one, why is the id still incremented as though the first weren't deleted? Is there a way to prevent this from happening so it can be as though the original row weren't there? Here's an example

```
Teachers
id   first_name
0    joe
1    mike
2    jim
```

If I delete "jim" then insert "bob" then bob's id will be 3 and there will be no entry with an id of 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132439/mysql-auto-decrementing-value

Comment: You really shouldn't be concerning yourself with the actual values allocated by autoincrement ids

Comment: Cool id's don't get recycled. Are _you_ going to keep track if id=1234 means the record that was in the database 1 week ago, 4 days ago, or just now?

Comment: keys don't get recycled to avoid id collision. they have to be unique for each transaction or you will run in to big problems

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. To me, what looks like the most important information is the key doesn't matter, it just has to be unique. That being said, if I really want to go in and make it my own, I can look at some of the information mentioned below to force a table to reset the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting any given row will not change the current auto increment value.

You can view the current value of the auto increment variable for the table by running

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'mytable';
```

And you can change the auto increment value by running

```
ALTER TABLE 'mytable' AUTO_INCREMENT = '1234';
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your **id** column was configured as autoincremental, and can't have the same value, unless you specify this manually

Comment: So does it store the last inserted ID and not the last existing ID?

Comment: Yep! Id take the next incremental

Answer (score 0):

you may also use ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 if after deleting the row and before inserting the new one, in order to make the id incrementation start at 2

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute this command after every delete operation , this will reset your auto_increment to 1 witch will be set automatically the the last available id ( 2 in your example )

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```